# syntax highlighting in ranger

Tags: syntax-highlighting, ranger

I've been playing around with ranger in emacs and I'm really liking it for browsing new codebases. I would like to get syntax highlighting working, as it does when using ranger in a terminal. I'm not seeing much documentation around getting it working in ranger code previews in emacs.

MacOS

```
$ brew install ranger
$ brew install highlight
$ ranger --copy-config=all
$ ranger
```

this installs and launches ranger from the terminal and does syntax highlighting when I select most files containing code (`.sh`, `.py`, `.go`, `.json`, etc) . Also populated `~/.config/ranger` with `scope.sh`, etc

Emacs init.el

```
(use-package ranger :ensure t)
(use-package highlight :ensure t)
```

ranger works great in emacs when I launch using `M-x ranger`, but I have no syntax highlighting when I select any files containing python, bash, go, etc code.

Comment: Please clarify *how* you use ranger (i.e. after which operations do you fail to see syntax highlighting)

Comment: updated my question to hopefully clarify

Comment: According to the [`ranger.el` docs](https://github.com/ralesi/ranger.el#window-conventions-for-range), _Selected files are previewed literally (raw) without any formatting, by default. To toggle between a fully formatted or a literal preview, press: `zi`..._ Have you tried that?

Comment: yes, `zi` works. I missed that in the docs. Do you want to submit an answer so I can accept?